# How to import socket.io-client to every component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm building an app with a chat right now using Socket.IO and I have a counter of how many users are connected

My problem is that when only one user is connected, the counter shows 3. Why 3 ? Because I have 3 components and I'm importing socket.io-client in each of those like that

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io();

export default {
   // bla bla bla
}
```

How can I import it once and make it available everywhere in my app ? I tried to import it in main.js then using it like

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
createApp(App)
  .use(io)
  .mount("#app");
```

But in my components when I do `const socket = io()` it's considered not defined

Comment: @Dan It does but I can't manage to use both solutions... Why do they pass an object inside createApp and why do they use "Vue" instead of just createApp as the default ?

Comment: You can continue to pass your `App` object to the method.  I'm not sure why they show an empty object like that in the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties) but I just changed it in the linked answer

Comment: @Dan I made it work, thank you a lot!! I was doing it [wrong](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/51/2/1608066202-image.png) ahah

Answer (score 0):

You can make it available for all your components by adding it as an instance property.

**For VuejS 3**

In your main.js

```
import { soketio } from 'socket.io-client'

const app = createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$soketio = soketio
app.mount("#app")
```

**For VuejS 2**

In your main.js

```
import { soketio } from 'socket.io-client'

Vue.prototype.$soketio = soketio;
new Vue({ render: h => h(App) }).$mount('#app')
```

In any component, you can access it using "this", like any other instance property for both Vuejs 2 and Vuejs3

```
this.$soketio ...
```

For more details see [Vuejs 3.x Global API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp).

For more details see [Vuejs 2.x Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html).

Good luck.